# Envio msg por whatsapp de for direta por uma aplicação

Tags: java, android, android-studio, whatsapp

É possivel o envio de mensagem via whatsapp para um contato pre determinado de forma direta da minha aplicação. Sem abrir a aplicação e tendo que selecionar o contato e ai enviar a mensagem.